# Correct Java dependencies installed for eclipse ADT development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have eclipse and the ADT bundle correctly installed on my home PC, and tried to install it on my laptop so I can work on my projects on the go. However, I either didn't set the java paths correctly, or installed them in the wrong place, because I can't get a default project to load without errors.

I have correctly:

-Installed the ADT bundle and launched eclipse without errors

-Created a workspace

-Correctly Installed both the jre8 and jdk1.8.0_05 in the location C:\Program Files\Java

I am very new to Android development, and I feel like I was lucky to set up the Java dependencies correctly on my home PC, no such luck this time from what the error look like...

However, when I try to make a basic "Hello world" project, I immediately get the following error:

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\userName\workspace\appcompat_v7_3\bin\appcompat_v7_3.jar'

[image: My Error]

I have tried adding the library, by checking build configurations, but I don't understand fully whats going on to correctly solve the problem. Here is my workspace:

[image: My Workspace]

And lastly, I tried checking the build configurations to see that the libraries are, in fact, missing. Or something like that. I am not sure if I should just try to reinstall java and the jdk.

Build configuration:
[image]

Anyway, I'm not sure what I deleted, misplaced, uninstalled, or didn't install, but if anyone could point me to a solution I would be very grateful. If anyone has any other questions on my setup I will try and be as thorough as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I have had issues like this if not running eclipse as Administrator.  Make sure that you aren't being blocked here.

**EDIT:** Please note Chris Stratton's concers regarding running an IDE as Administrator, as seen in the comments below.

**EDIT 2:** In my more recent experience, I have noticed that if I installed the SDK by copying and pasting the contents of the downloaded, compressed, folder to a destination rather than extracting it first, I would be required to run as Administrator.  If this is the case, delete the SDK that you copied out of the compressed folder and simply extract the contents of the downloaded compressed folder.  I am running Windows 7 so it is likely that this applies to all Windows 7 and 8 OS's.

In another case, I have also seen issues like this if the JRE is installed second rather than first.  In this case, a reinstall of the SDK is probably all that is required.

Comment: It would really be preferable not to run an IDE such as Eclipse under an administrator account.

Comment: I understand, and this is a valid desire, but a fresh Windows 7 Professional install has done this to me.  I'm just trying to help Tyler Jones get to the bottom of his issue.  Once the problem is understood, he can modify privileges however he likes.

Comment: Actually, cleaning up from the leave-behinds of having *ever* run something as privileged account can be a royal pain, and is a key reason not to do it.

Comment: Thank you @N8sBug! Running it as an administrator cleared up all erros I had, hopefully I don't run into any in the future. Any idea why this is an issue on my laptop, running windows 8, while my home PC which also runs windows 8, seemed to work fine? Thanks so much for the help, frustrating that I spent three hours looking at downloads at paths last night when all that was needed to fix it was two right clicks... Haha

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Can you please explain what issues you can see me running into? I am a pretty new user of the ADT, and if you see this as being a short run solution, do you have any idea of what I should be doing?

Comment: Embrassing a change to learn here.  If privileges is an/the issue, how else would you get to the bottom of it?  Eclipse will start under the circumstance of insufficient privileges, but provides some less than intuitive error messages.

Comment: Running a complex package like an IDE as a privileged users tends to leave behind a sprinkling of files owned by that user, which a normal account can neither overwrite, nor remove, leading to hard-to-understand errors.

Comment: @Tyler Jones, running windows 7 at home too. I have both a win7 laptop and desktop. Have the EXACT same problem. Laptop I always run as administrator. Might want to refer this to superuser.com on elevating privileges for a particular application/user.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Acknowledged your concerns in the edit to the answer above.  Thanks for your thoughts.